# Problema ao renderizar página JSF

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces, maven

Estou com um problema bem "chato", ontem tinha um sistema `JSF` funcionando perfeitamente com todas as páginas abrindo corretamente. Quando entro no sistema hoje a página está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nenhum componente do `Primefaces` ou `JSF` está funcionando mais. Já é a terceira vez que acontece isso e até agora eu fico sem entender o porque. A única solução que encontrei foi iniciar um novo projeto e copiar tudo pra ele, mas gostaria de saber o que poderia ser esse problema.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Inventario</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        *.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Estou usando `Maven` em meu projeto, e tenho todas as dependências certas.